# Programmaticaly get header-args property value

Tags: org-mode

In my org mode file, I have defined some [header-args](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-Header-Arguments.html).

In an emacs-lisp code I use `org-entry-get-with-inheritance`to retrieve them. By example

```
(org-entry-get-with-inheritance "header-args:julia")
```

returns me this string:

```
":exports code :tangle-mode (identity #o555) :mkdirp yes :eval never :comments link :tangle yes :tangle ../../test/QuadraticSolvers/runtests.jl"
```

Now I want to get the value associated to the symbol ":tangle" (here ../../test/QuadraticSolvers/runtests.jl)

This can be done with a regex, but I guess it already exists an org-mode function for this task.

Do you know this function ?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Drew thanks. I finally found a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are calling your program while your cursor is in the source block of interest, you can use `org-babel-get-src-block-info` to get all of the info. You can then get the alist of header args with `(caddr (org-babel-get-src-block-info))` and use `assq` to get the `:tangle` entry:

```el
(assq :tangle (caddr (org-babel-get-src-block-info)))
```

That should take care of all headers, whether they are attached to the source block or are defined as properties.

You could combine this with `org-babel-find-named-block` to do what you have described in your answer:

```el
(defun my1-get-babel-tangled-file (name)
   (save-excursion
       (goto-char (org-babel-find-named-block name))
       (cdr (assq :tangle (caddr (org-babel-get-src-block-info))))))
```

Error handling is non-existent but the basic idea is sound, I think.

But this requires that you name your source blocks:

```
#+name: foo
#+begin_src julia
...
#+end_src
```

However, that is always a good idea IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to NickD and Drew for their help & advice

I finally found a solution to my problem. Even if it is much longer than expected (meaning that there is certainly a shorter/more elegant solution)

The function that helped me is `org-babel-parse-header-arguments`. It parses the returned string from `org-entry-get-with-inheritance` and return an alist :

```
(org-babel-parse-header-arguments (org-entry-get-with-inheritance "header-args:julia"))
```

gives

```
((:exports . "code") (:tangle-mode . 365) (:mkdirp . "yes") (:eval . "never") (:comments . "link") (:tangle . "yes") (:tangle . "../../test/QuadraticSolvers/runtests.jl"))
```

Then I had to modify the `rassq-delete-all` as it uses `eq`, and not `equal` as required for strings.

I also had to manage the fact that the same `:tangle` symbol can be used several times with "yes", "no" or with the filename I am looking for.

Here is my code

```
(defun my1--assoc-delete-all-yes-no-cdr (alist)
  "Check ALIST `car', return `t' if its  `cdr' is `equal' to \"yes\" or \"no\""
  (let ((tocheck (cdr (car alist))))
    (or (equal tocheck "yes") (equal tocheck "no"))))

(defun my1-assoc-delete-all-yes-no-cdr (alist)
  "Delete from ALIST all elements whose cdr is `equal' to \"yes\" or \"no\"
Return the modified alist.
(inspired from `rassq-delete-all')"
  (while (my1--assoc-delete-all-yes-no-cdr alist)
    (setq alist (cdr alist)))
  (let ((tail alist) tail-cdr)
    (while (setq tail-cdr (cdr tail))
      (if (my1--assoc-delete-all-yes-no-cdr tail-cdr)
      (setcdr tail (cdr tail-cdr))
    (setq tail tail-cdr))))
  alist)

(defun my1--get-babel-header-argument-as-alist (lang symbol)
  "Return babel header argument as an alist
Example (my1--get-babel-header-argument-as-alist \"julia\" :tangle)."
  (let ((header-arg-lang (concat "header-args" ":" lang)))
    (assoc-delete-all
     symbol
     (org-babel-parse-header-arguments
      (org-entry-get-with-inheritance header-arg-lang)) (lambda (a b) (not (equal a b))))))

(defun my1-get-babel-tangled-file (lang)
  "Return tangled file from header-args (if any) for the given LANG
Exemple: (my1-get-babel-tangled-file \"julia\")"
  (cdr
   (car
    (my1-assoc-delete-all-yes-no-cdr
     (my1--get-babel-header-argument-as-alist lang :tangle)))))
```

Here is a demo, with more context. I use literate programming and tangle a lot of pieces of code. At some point (for unit tests by example), I want a **generic** script to do something with the tangled code. That is the reason why I wanted to programmatically retrieve the current `:tangle`.

```
* Demo
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:julia: :tangle yes :tangle julia_code.jl :exports code :tangle-mode (identity #o555) :mkdirp yes :eval never :comments link 
:END:

#+begin_src julia
  # my julia code
#+end_src

Literate programming here... :)

#+begin_src julia
  println("hello world...")
#+end_src

Now do something with my julia code

#+begin_src sh :var file=(my1-get-babel-tangled-file "julia")"
echo "Do something with $file"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: Do something with julia_code.jl
```

Comment: Note that `:tangle yes :tangle /path/to/file` is equivalent to `:tangle /path/to/file`: the last `:tangle` wins.

Comment: @NickD thanks for the clarification. It is “unfortunate” that the **last** tangle wins but the `assoc` function returns the **first** occurrence. Maybe reversing the alist is an idea ?

Comment: The advantage of `org-babel-get-src-blockinfo` is that it already has done all the appropriate reductions: you will only have *one* `:tangle` in its output, the operative one.

Comment: I do agree but how to use it in my context ? I will dig a little more, I'm not very happy with my current solution, which is certainly over complex.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! Yes that's really shorter. The extra work of introducing a block code name is a lesser evil compared to the complexity of my solution. Moreover the approach is more robust.

Comment: It is not a "lesser evil": it is a "greater good" :-)