# How to tangle code blocks from an org file, compile the output, and open the result, with a single command?

Tags: org-mode, latex, bash, tangle, lilypond

I use `org-babel-tangle` to generate lilypond and latex documents from org files.

These org files have the following first line:

`#+PROPERTY: header-args :LANG :comments org :tangle PATH/FILE_NAME.EXT`

Where

- LANG is either latex or lilypond
- PATH is a specific (each time different) path
- FILE_NAME is a specific (each time different) file name
- EXT is either tex or ly

At first, I was compiling the generated .ly/.tex to pdf from the terminal. But then I started putting a function on each org file to generate and open PDFs. Here is the function for tex documents:

```
  (defun mda/tex-pdf ()
    "Produce a Xelatex PDF from an org file containing tex blocks."
    (interactive)
    (org-babel-tangle)
    (cd "PATH")
    (shell-command "xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode NAME_FILE.tex")
    (shell-command "evince NAME_FILE.pdf"))
```

I can add easily this function with skeleton, but I have to change PATH once and NAME_FILE twice each time.

I there a way to automatically pick up PATH, and NAME_FILE from the first line? This way I could move the 2 functions to my config file.

**EDIT**:

It appears that the use case description wasn't precise enough.

So in this use case, every source block in the Org mode file uses the same language and the same `:tangle` path spec (which is specified once, in `#+PROPERTY: header-args :...`). So that all the tangled blocks end up in the exact same file.

Comment: You'll have to do your own loop over code blocks but you can use `org-babel-get-src-block-info` to get at the header args.

Comment: Thank you @NickD `org-babel-get-src-block-info` is very useful indeed. However, I can't find how to make it work when called from a function evaluated outside of the tangled buffer (see my edit for more details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each block in the file uses its own language and/or its own tangle
path, then you will have to examine each one separately. That's what I
assumed at first and that assumption is behind my original comment:
you would have to loop over all of the blocks and treat each one
separately.

But after you added clarifications in the comments (which should
really be in the question itself), the following answer assumes that
every source block in the Org mode file uses the same language and the
same `:tangle` path spec, so that *all* the tangled blocks end up in
the exact same file. There is then no need to examine *each* source
block for those values: they will all have the same values, so getting
the values from one of them should be enough.

Proceeding on that assumption, we end up with something like this:

```el
(defun my/get-lang-and-path ()
  "Get lang and path info from the first source block in the file"
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (org-babel-next-src-block)
    (let* ((info (org-babel-get-src-block-info))
           (lang (car info))
           (path (cdr (assq :tangle (caddr info)))))
      (if (null info)
          nil
        (list lang path)))))

(defun mda/tangle-tex-compile-open-pdf()
  "Generate and open a PDF from an org file containing tex blocks."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((info (my/get-lang-and-path))
         (lang (car info))
         (path (cadr info))
         (directory (file-name-directory path))
         (filename (file-name-nondirectory path))
         (basename (file-name-base path)))
    ;; tangle all the code blocks
    (org-babel-tangle)
    (let ((default-directory (expand-file-name (or directory "."))))
      ;; generate PDF file - appropriate command depends on language
      (cond
       ((string= lang "latex")
        (shell-command (concat "xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode " filename)))
       ((string= lang "lilypond")
        (shell-command (concat "lilypond " filename)))
       (t
        (message "Unknown language")))
      ;; ...and show it if it exists
      (if (file-exists-p (concat basename ".pdf"))
          (shell-command (concat "evince " basename ".pdf"))
        (message "%s.pdf does not exist in directory %s" basename default-directory)))))
```

There is no error checking, but the code does not barf with or without code blocks. I tested with

```bash
emacs -q -l foo.el foo.org
```

where `foo.el` includes the two functions shown above and `foo.org` looks like this:

```org
#+PROPERTY: header-args :comments org :tangle tangle/foo.tex

* Test

#+name: doc-preamble
#+begin_src latex
  \documentclass{article}

  \begin{document}
#+end_src

#+name:doc-body
#+begin_src latex

  \int_0^\infty 1 dx = \infty
#+end_src

#+begin_src latex
\end{document}
#+end_src
```

or like this:

```org
#+PROPERTY: header-args :comments org :tangle tangle/foo.tex

* Test

No code blocks here.
```

I get reasonable behavior in either case, although the error handling in the second case is insufficient for "production" use.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help NickD! I edited the question as you recommended. Your code works perfectly. I will now try to extend the use case, so your code can work even when a path isn't provided (as for now, with `#+PROPERTY: header-args :comments org :tangle FILE-NAME.EXT` the function shows the following error `let: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`).

Comment: I made a change to the `expand-file-name` call to catch this case. Try it out and let me know.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I was trying to implement it with an `if`, but your solution is much smarter. I changed `(shell-command (concat "evince " basename ".pdf"))` to `(shell-command (concat "evince " basename ".pdf &"))`, in order to run `evince` in background, so the org file can still be edited.

Comment: Yes, thre is plenty of space for improvement and elaboration. I'm sure there will be other cases where it fails too (but if you run into them, I'll do my best to fix them).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @NickD, I managed to build a function from the `full-path (cdr (assq :tangle (caddr (org-babel-get-src-block-info))))` command that you provided [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74782/programmaticaly-get-header-args-property-value).

Here it is:

```el
  (defun mda/tangle-tex-compile-open-pdf()
    "Generate and open a PDF from an org file containing tex blocks."
    (interactive)
    (org-babel-tangle)
    (let ((mda/var (cdr (assq :tangle (caddr(org-babel-get-src-block-info))))))
      (cd (file-name-directory mda/var))
      (shell-command (concat "xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode " (file-name-nondirectory mda/var)))
      (shell-command (concat "evince " (file-name-base mda/var) ".pdf"))))
```

Oddly, this function only works when it is evaluated from the buffer where the `#+PROPERTY: header-args :LANG :comments org :tangle PATH/FILE_NAME.EXT` is located. When it is evaluated from init, running it gives the following error: `cd: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`. Meaning that `mda/var` is nil...

Comment: There is nothing odd about that if you *call* the function from your init file: it will only work if the current buffer is an Org mode file where each code block has a `:tangle` header arg of the appropriate form (either individually or set with a property). You can *define* the function in your init file, but you can not call it there. In addition, as I mentioned, you'll have to implement your own loop: `org-babel-get-src-block` assumes that it is called with `point` *in the source block*: if you call it from elsewhere, it will return `nil`, so you cannot call `org-babel-tangle`...

Comment: You'll have to use a mapping function (like `org-babel-map-src-blocks`) and evaluate a function that tangles the current source block only (using `org-babel-get-src-block-info` on the current block to glean the info you need).

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my explanation. I always call the function from an org file containing latex or lilypond source blocks and `#+PROPERTY: header-args :LANG :comments org :tangle PATH/FILE_NAME.EXT` in the first line. When the function is compiled inside the tangled buffer it works, but when it is not (when it is only present in the init) it doesn't.

Comment: So it's the second comment that is applicable: you'll have to implement your own loop using the mapping function - you cannot call `org-babel-tangle` to tangle them all first.

Comment: You cannot use a single `#+PROPERTY` line for every block: LANG and PATH and FILENAME are different for each block - no?

Comment: I only have a single `#+PROPERTY` line at the beginning of each concerned org file. Each of these org files contain either only tex blocks  (`#+begin_src latex`) or only lilypond blocks (`#+begin_src lilypond`).

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge is not advanced enough to be able to understand your comment about the mapping function.

Comment: So all the blocks in a single org file use the same language. Do they all use the same `:tangle` path too? You say "each time different" for PATH and FILE, so it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: There is only one `:tangle`, per concerned org file, which is inside the `#+PROPERTY: header-args...` line, located at the beginning of these org files. There is only one `PATH` too, located after the `:tangle`. "each time different" means that each of these org files uses a different `PATH`.