# How to fix "cd: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil" error?

Tags: org-mode, debugging

I use `org-babel-tangle` to generate latex documents from org files.

These org files have the following first line:

`#+PROPERTY: header-args :latex :comments org :tangle PATH/FILE_NAME.tex`

I built a function to tangle to tex, compile the tex, and open the generated PDF:

```el
  (defun mda/tangle-tex-compile-open-pdf()
    "Generate and open a PDF from an org file containing tex blocks."
    (interactive)
    (org-babel-tangle)
    (setq full-path-tex (cdr (assq :tangle (caddr (org-babel-get-src-block-info)))))
    (current-buffer)
    (cd (file-name-directory full-path-tex))
    (shell-command (concat "xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode " (file-name-nondirectory full-path-tex)))
    (shell-command (concat "evince " (file-name-base full-path-tex) ".pdf")))
```

I put this function in my init. When I execute it, it produces the following error :

`cd: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`

What I don't understand is that when I run

```el
    (setq full-path-tex (cdr (assq :tangle (caddr (org-babel-get-src-block-info)))))
    (current-buffer)
    (cd (file-name-directory full-path-tex))
    (shell-command (concat "xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode " (file-name-nondirectory full-path-tex)))
    (shell-command (concat "evince " (file-name-base full-path-tex) ".pdf"))
```

from org files, I have no errors and everything works fine...

Comment: The error msg is telling you that `(cdr (assq :tangle (caddr (org-babel-get-src-block-info))))` return `nil`, not an absolute file name. Why this is the case when you call the function and not when you eval the code from an Org buffer, I don't know. A guess is that in the context of Ords `(org-babel-get-src-block-info)` gives you something useful and outside that context it doesn't. Try `M-x debug-on-entry RET mda/tangle-tex-compile-open-pdf RET`, and walk through the debugger with `d`, to see what goes wrong.

Comment: `debug-on-entry RET mda/tangle-tex-compile-open-pdf RET` doesn't do anything. I don't even have an error message. And when I press `d`, I just see the letter d wirrtten down in the buffer.

Comment: If the debugger (buffer `*Backtrace*` doesn't open after you've done `M-x debug-on-entry...` and retried your code, then `mda/tangle-tex-compile-open-pdf` isn't getting called, for some reason (?). If the debugger does open, the `d` **in the debugger window** steps through the evaluation of that function call.

Comment: I managed to get the `*Backtrace*` buffer. After doing `M-x debug-on-entry RET mda/tangle-tex-compile-open-pdf RET` once, the debugger appears each time I do `M-x  mda/tangle-tex-compile-open-pdf RET`. I now have to understand how the debugger works, I'll try to find some tutorial.

Comment: You should probably not use `cd` in a function: it is meant for interactively changing the currenct directory of a buffer. You are better off let-binding `default-directory`. See my answer to your [related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78856/how-to-retrieve-tangle-location-from-header-args) which indirectly also answers this question.

Comment: Thanks @NickD for your explanation. Also, @Drew was right about the error msg telling me that `(cdr (assq :tangle (caddr (org-babel-get-src-block-info))))` returns nil.  BTW I didn't manage to understand how to take advantage of the `*Backtrace* ` buffer. Shall I delete this question, since the problem is solved [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78856/how-to-retrieve-tangle-location-from-header-args)?